# Pandas value_counts group sum dependent on another column within a groupby.agg function

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I am currently aggregating a set of variables grouped and aggregated by variables`var1 and var2`. Let's assume I do have continuous variables `var3, var4, var5` where I calculate the mean, std, min, max and median values within aggregated groups easily. However, I also do have two more variables `var6 and var7` where `var6` is a categorical variable and continuous `var7` variable that shows the size of `var6`. My dataframe looks as follows:

```
var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7
1    a    3    8     9   0    125
1    a    4    0     12  0    12 
1    a    12   4     12  2    3
1    b    24   5     1   1    45
2    a    1    19    4   1    76
2    a    2    37    12  1    12
2    c    3    93    156 1    341
2    c    57   1     87  2    73
2    c    42   4     95  2    95
3    b    12   11    0   0    11
3    b    119  0     901 0    5
```

The first part, where I calculate grouped aggregation is easy as follows (as an example):

```
desired_df=my_df.groupby(['var1', 'var2']).agg(
    max_var3=('var3', 'max')
    mean_var4=(var4, 'min'))
```

What I desire to do on top of this aggregation is to group `var6` and `var7` and put them as new columns next to the aggregation. Below is what I like to do:

```
var1 var2 var6_group0_sum var6_group1_sum var6_group2_sum
1    a        137         0               3
1    b        0           0               45
2    a        0           88              0
2    c        0           341             168
3    b        16           0               0
```

How can I achieve this within grouped aggregation? Any help appreciated.

Comment: you'll probably have to do them separately, then recombine

Answer (score 1):

Get the aggregation without the categorical columns (copied and pasted your code):

```
left = (df.groupby(['var1', 'var2'])
         .agg(max_var3=('var3', 'max'),
              mean_var4=('var4', 'min'))
        )
```

Get the aggregation of just the categorical column:

```
right = (df.groupby(['var1', 'var2', 'var6'])
           .var7
           .sum()
           .unstack(-1, fill_value = 0)
           .rename(columns = lambda col: f'var6_group{col}_sum')
           .rename_axis(columns = None)
          )
```

Combine the two dataframes, note that they share the same index:

```
pd.concat([left, right], axis = 1)

           max_var3  mean_var4  var6_group0_sum  var6_group1_sum  var6_group2_sum
var1 var2                                                                        
1    a           12          0              137                0                3
     b           24          5                0               45                0
2    a            2         19                0               88                0
     c           57          1                0              341              168
3    b          119          0               16                0                0
```

Comment: So this is one of the solutions I am aware but I absolutely want to do it in the same aggregation if possible. This would be very easy to do in R. I am switching from R to Python, and I don't think Python is less capable in this sense. I tried to declare and use variables within aggregation (i.e. wanted to use min_var3 after declaration in another lambda function to calculate some other variables) but it does throw an error and not seem possible. If it was possible to use previously declared variables within aggregation, maybe this would have been relatively easier.

Comment: kindly elaborate more on your code. post a solution that uses dplyr. Possibly be a good way for me to learn something new